# Safe way to update DIV with other page-content

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, html

I'm wondering what is the **best and safest** way to make a redirect in a div after submitting a form.
So, I have a form with a calulation inside a div. When the calculation is 0 I would like to show page_zero.php into this div instead of the form.

Here is some code:

**form_page.php**

```
<div class="form_wrapper">
    <div id="PP_succes_engine" style=""></div>
    <form id="SignupForm" action="" method="post" ONSubmit="xmlhttpPost('invoice_engine.php', 'SignupForm', 'PP_succes_engine', '<div class=\'PP_wait_loading\'></div>');return false;  ">
    <?php
    //calculation
    ?>
    <input name="tot_price" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tot_price; ?>">

    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="type-button">
</div>
```

**invoice_engine.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_POST['tot_price'] == 0) {
    // REDIRECT ME TO 'page_zero.php' BUT STAY INTO <div class="form_wrapper">
}
else {
   // RUN OTHER SCRIPT
}
?>
```

Comment: you cant redirect a div, you redirect a whole page. and you have to make sure you  redirect before you display any content

Comment: you are right, redirect is a wrong term. I altered the title hoping it is more clear now

Comment: define **"safe"** like all warm and cozy feeling with no sharp functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_POST['tot_price'] == 0){
    include 'page_zero.php';
    exit;
else ...
```

You can just include. Why redirect?

Comment: this won't update the <div class="form_wrapper"> just put page_zero.php on top of it in the <div id="PP_succes_engine">

Answer (score 0):

Life would be simpler and cleaner to implement using jQuery:

Have a read through: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Not exactly what you're looking for but all the elements are there.

Basically, you can call your invoice_engine.php and get it to return HTML that you can then 'inject' into a DIV on your page.

Comment: thank you for this, but I don't want to put all of my jQuery on top of it. Thats why I'm looking for something safe. The jquery I need depends on the page I include / load